# Navbar not working properly on different screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a multi-screen compatible navbar (mainly mobile and desktop users). I have created the styling I want for the navbar, however, I have a minor problem: When expanding the navbar on medium devices (768px or below) and then close it, if the user changes the resolution size to > 768px, the side navbar doesn't show.

```js
function sideNavAction() {
  let sidenav = document.getElementById("sideNavBar");
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(sidenav).display);
  if (window.getComputedStyle(sidenav).display == "none") {
    sidenav.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    sidenav.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.mobile-nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: grey;
}

.nav-brand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
}

.nav-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-heading h2 {
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-icon {
  text-align: center;
}

.sidenav {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.sidenav .nav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidenav .nav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: 0.16s;
}

#expand-icon {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.sidenav-links a {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9697aa;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #9697aa;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.active {
  background-color: #1b1b28;
}

.active i {
  color: #5d78ff;
}

.active .link {
  color: white;
}

.fas {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidenav {
    display: block;
  }

  .sidenav .nav-brand {
    display: flex;
  }

  .sidenav:not(:hover) {
    width: 75px;
  }

  .sidenav:not(:hover) .nav-heading h2 {
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.1s 0.2s;
  }

  .sidenav:not(:hover) #expand-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  .sidenav-links a:hover {
    background-color: #1b1b28;
    color: #5d78ff;
  }

  .sidenav-links a:hover .link {
    color: white;
    transition: none;
  }

  .sidenav:not(:hover) .link {
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.1s 0.2s;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidenav .nav-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Online CV</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="mobile-nav">
      <div class="nav-brand">
        <div class="nav-heading">
          <h2>Navbar</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-icon">
          <button onclick="sideNavAction()">
            <i id="collapse-icon" class="fas fa-fw fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidenav" id="sideNavBar">
      <div class="nav-brand">
        <div class="nav-heading">
          <h2>Navbar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-icon">
          <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-fw fa-angle-double-left fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sidenav-links">
        <a class="active" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="link">Link 1</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="link">Link 2</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="link">Link 3</p>
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="link">Link 4</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I realize that my JS function is the cause of this, as it sets the display of the side nav to 'none', but I am unable to think of an elegant solution.

Comment: Instead of using JS to apply styles directly, apply a class that only sets styles for your navbar within the media query for smaller screens.

Comment: How am I able to achieve this if I want the styling of the navbar to change on a button click?

Comment: Same as you're doing now with the `sidenav.style.display`, but instead use `sidenav.classList.add('navbar-mobile-visible')` or `.remove('navbar-mobile-visible')` and create a `.navbar-mobile-visible` class within your media query. You can leverage `classList.contains('navbar-mobile-visible')` instead of `getComputedStyle`

Comment: This solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chriskirknielsen, I was able to come up with this solution which fixed the problem I was having.

```
/* --- Function to Open/Close Mobile Nav --- */
function sideNavAction() {
  let sidenav = document.getElementById("sideNavBar");
  if (sidenav.classList.contains("sidenav-mobile-visible")) {
    sidenav.classList.remove("sidenav-mobile-visible");
  } else {
    sidenav.classList.add("sidenav-mobile-visible");
  }
}
```

Then added this in my css file

```
.sidenav-mobile-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

1. Inline eventlisteners are frowned upon.
   Better to listen for click events via Javascript.
2. You added a stye of `display: none;` and there is no eventListener or media query to change it once the width increased beyond the threshold.

This codepen has the above adjustments:

https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/poJEOYE?editors=1111

And should work as intended.

However, I added a media query and targeted the nav class with a `!important` tag. That should, ideally, never be done. I would suggest, removing the `!important` and playing around with the code until it works without it.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you using Bootstrap "navbar" component? This is the solution to your problem. 
Bootstrap navbar is responsive for desktop and mobile devices. You are not required to mention screen sizes there in pixels. Here is the link of the Bootstrap library. You have to just integrate Bootstrap to your html document via Bootstrap CDN on the given link.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I'm trying to create it with just html, css and js instead of an external library

Comment: Loading in an entire library to achieve this would be absolute overkill, and doesn't help OP in learning how to do this.

Comment: Totally agree with JLi2398 why should the OP use external library with more complex things to handle and what about implementing the pure css were you have better control and better learning also